# Why aren't we getting Hulk sequels in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk

Since the launch of the Marvel Cinematic Universe, we've had three Iron Man movies, two Thor movies, and two Captain America movies, but only one Hulk movie. Why? Why aren't we getting more Hulk movies? Any official words?

Comment: There have been rumors that Widow or Hulk will die in *Age of Ultron*.

Comment: Probably because Hulk only has one story other than avengers.

Comment: @phantom42 Not saying it's impossible, but it seems unlikely that Hulk will; Mark Ruffalo has a 6-film contract with Marvel Studios, and [Kevin Feige has said](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Why-Hulk-Isn-t-Getting-His-Own-Solo-Movie-Marvel-Studios-Phase-3-67926.html) that he's on board at least through *Infinity War*

Comment: @JasonBaker Yeah just pointing out the existence of the rumors which, if true, would explain it. It's just uncorroborated rumors and speculation right now though, so not an answer.

Comment: @user111737 What does it mean that Hulk has only one story? Story can always be created. Also, don't forget he has got a long list of stories from comics.

Comment: Ever since _Avengers_ I've been enjoying the irony that Hulk seems to work better as part of a team.

Comment: I won't post it as an answer until I find the quote, but there was an interview with Whedon where he talked about how incredibly expensive the Hulk is to animate.  All the muscle work and facial animations, etc, make it a lot more expensive to make a movie where the star isn't even real.  That, plus the fact that the Hulk hasn't done well in solo films, makes it safer to have him when he's with a bunch of other box office draws, like the Avengers.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I was surprised to learn that there actually *is* some official word on this.

### Why no Hulk sequels?

[CinemaBlend.com reports](https://www.cinemablend.com/new/Why-Marvel-Doesn-t-Really-Want-Give-Hulk-Movie-68713.html) on some commentary made by Joss Whedon on the set of *Age of Ultron*. According to Whedon, it was a decision made by Marvel Studios to keep Hulk an *Avengers*-exclusive character:

> The writer/director was discussing the use of Hulk in the movie and the fact that he didn't have his own Phase 2 solo film, and he remembered a conversation he had with Marvel Studios President Kevin Feige. Whedon quoted the executive, saying that he was told, "We think right now it’s good to have somebody who we could only have in *The Avengers*"

### Okay, but why Hulk, specifically?

In principle any character could be an *Avengers*-exclusive, and some of them sort of are: neither Black Widow nor Hawkeye have had solo films, and there doesn't seem to be any plans to make them.

In an [article on Forbes.com](https://www.forbes.com/sites/markhughes/2015/06/19/details-of-marvels-hulk-film-rights-fans-can-relax-about-sequel/), former film writer Mark Hughes reports that the distribution rights for the Hulk character are owned by Universal, not Marvel:

> But despite obtaining the cinematic rights to make Hulk movies, Marvel did not obtain distribution rights. Universal held those rights, and today I can confirm the exact situation is that Universal currently retains *the right of first refusal* to distribute any Hulk films in the future. If for some reason Universal chose to forgo distribution, then Disney would immediately pick up the distribution rights for the Hulk movie.

This is clearly not an insurmountable obstacle; Marvel and Universal managed to come to an arrangement to release *The Incredible Hulk*, so in theory they could do so again.

However, Marvel has no good motivation to do this; of all their solo characters, Hulk has proven to be the worst box office draw. I made a graph comparing the budget of each MCU film (at time of posting, so no *Age of Ultron*) to total box office revenue. I also threw [Ang Lee's *Hulk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_(film)) on the end, because that film's performance is very relevant when talking about a Hulk solo film. The blue bar is the budget (in unadjusted millions), and the orange is global box office revenue (also unadjusted millions):

[image: We got us a bar graph over here]

<sup><sub>Numbers from BoxOfficeMojo: [*Hulk*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=hulk.htm), [*Iron Man*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=ironman.htm), [*The Incredible Hulk*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=incrediblehulk.htm), [*Iron Man 2*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=ironman2.htm),[*Thor*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=thor.htm) , [*Captain America*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=captainamerica.htm), [*The Avengers*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=avengers11.htm), [*Iron Man 3*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=ironman3.htm), [*Thor 2*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=thor2.htm), [*The Winter Soldier*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=marvel14b.htm), [*Guardians of the Galaxy*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=marvel2014a.htm)</sub></sup>

If I'm a studio executive looking to evaluate how smart of an investment a movie is, what I'm looking at is how big the orange bar is compared to the blue bar. If they're exactly the same height, I broke even; no profit<sup>1</sup>.

*Hulk* just about doubled its budget; it was made for $137 million, and box office revenue was only $245 million. *The Incredible Hulk* actually did slightly worse: it made $263 million at the box office, but cost Marvel Studios $150 million to make.

In comparison, the next-lowest performing MCU movie was *Captain America: The First Avenger*, which made back well more than twice its budget: Marvel Studios spent $140 million on it, and it made $371 million at the box office.

Meanwhile we have *The Avengers* sitting proudly on top, having earned a whopping *nine times* its budget at the box office.

As a studio executive, what do I take away from this? Hulk solo movies are an *incredibly* risky investment.

Just for giggles (and because today is a holiday and I literally have nothing better to occupy my time with), I decided to do a similar analysis for other films based on Marvel properties - I limited myself to movies made on or after the year 2000, since that's about when they started becoming, you know, [somewhat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America_(1990_film)) reliably [good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fantastic_Four_(unreleased_film)). The titles are ordered by how good of an investment they were<sup>2</sup>, so I added release year after the movie title:

[image: Another bar graph y'all]

<sup><sub>Once again, numbers from BoxOfficeMojo: [*Punisher: War Zone*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=punisher2.htm), [*Elektra*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=elektra.htm), [*Fantastic Four* (2015)](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=fantasticfour15.htm), [*The Punisher*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=punisher.htm), [*The Incredible Hulk*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=incrediblehulk.htm), [*Hulk*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=hulk.htm), [*Blade: Trinity*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=blade3.htm), [*Ghost Rider*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=ghostrider.htm), [*X-Men: The Last Stand*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=x3.htm), [*X-Men: First Class*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=xmenfirstclass.htm), [*Fantastic Four: Rise of the Silver Surfer*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=fantasticfour2.htm), [*Daredevil*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=daredevil.htm), [*Ghost Rider: Spirit of Vengeance*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=ghostrider2.htm), [*X-Men Origins: Wolverine*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=wolverine.htm), [*Captain America*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=captainamerica.htm), [*Blade II*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=blade2.htm), [*Thor*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=thor.htm), [*X-Men: Apocalypse*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=x-men2016.htm), [*Iron Man 2*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=ironman2.htm), [*The Amazing Spider-Man*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=spiderman4.htm), [*Fantastic Four* (2005)](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=fantasticfour.htm), [*Spider-Man 3*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=spiderman3.htm), [*The Wolverine*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=wolverine2.htm), [*The Amazing Spider-Man 2*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=amazingspiderman2.htm), [*X2: X-Men United*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=x2.htm), [*X-Men: Days of Future Past*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=xmen2014.htm), [*Thor: The Dark World*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=thor2.htm), [*Spider-Man 2*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=spiderman2.htm), [*X-Men*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=xmen.htm), [*Ant-Man*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=antman.htm), [*Doctor Strange*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=marvel716.htm), [*Iron Man*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=ironman.htm), [*Captain America: The Winter Soldier*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=marvel14b.htm), [*Guardians of the Galaxy*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=marvel2014a.htm), [*Captain America: Civil War*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=marvel2016.htm), [*Age of Ultron*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=avengers2.htm), [*Spider-Man*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=spiderman.htm), [*Iron Man 3*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=ironman3.htm), [*The Avengers*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=avengers11.htm), [*Logan*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=wolverine2017.htm), [*Deadpool*](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=deadpool2016.htm).</sub></sup>

As you can see, Hulk is one of the least bankable Marvel properties of the last twenty years. Only Elektra (who was probably as harmed by horrible reputation of the 2003 *Daredevil* film as anything else), Punisher (who, despite his tragic backstory, is one of the least sympathetic Marvel protagonists<sup>3, 4</sup>), and the Fantastic Four (whose latest outing was just so freaking bad) have made worse movies than Hulk.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is a vast oversimplification, but it serves well enough as a first approximation. These numbers only consider production budgets and box office earnings; in reality, there are many other sources of both revenue and costs that would go into deciding whether a particular movie was a good investment, including but not limited to:

- Marketing budgets, which in 2014 were allegedly hovering around $200 million per movie, [according to](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/200-million-rising-hollywood-struggles-721818) the *Hollywood Reporter*
- Home media sales
- [Merchandising](https://youtu.be/fgRFQJCHcPw?t=36s)
- Cross-promotional effects<sup>5</sup>
- [Intellectual property concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashcan_copy); as that link notes, it's occasionally considered worthwhile to make a movie solely as a means to hold onto the rights
- Actor royalties
- Distribution costs, which ties into the earlier discussion about Universal's ownership of the Hulk distribution rights
- Profit-sharing with theatres

Accurately calculating all of this would be *way* too much research, but *The Week* magazine [estimated in 2016](https://theweek.com/articles/647394/when-buy-movie-ticket-where-does-that-money) that about 4% of American box office revenue can be considered studio profit, and every $1 of box office revenue will earn an additional $1.75 [over the next ten years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_tail) through alternative distributions (like DVD sales)

This is also a simplified model (and doesn't get into the notoriously bizarre practice of [Hollywood accounting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_accounting), where technically almost no movie actually profits), but does help to explain why film studios are so risk-averse, even when the raw numbers are so outrageous

<sup>2</sup> Literally, by [rate of return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return), or how much profit they made as a percentage of budget

<sup>3</sup> Note that I didn't use the word "hero." Yeah, that was on purpose.

<sup>4</sup> That being said, kudos to *Daredevil*'s second season for simultaneously making Punisher into both a frothing lunatic and a sympathetic, quasi-heroic figure

<sup>5</sup> By which I basically mean: the effect that releasing a movie has on the products of other divisions; does releasing a new *Avengers* movie affect the ratings on the Marvel television shows, or the sales of Marvel comic books?

Comment: What a world we live in when making $110 million dollars profit isn't considered "profitable".

Comment: I think we would say 175% return and 265%, respectively because The incredible Hulk did not lose money.

Comment: @phantom42 Look at it this way: they can either do a Hulk movie that is likely to "fail", or they can spend that money on another movie which might be far more profitable.

Comment: it's unfortunate, because there's a lot of things you could put into a Hulk movie that would never make it into an ensemble movie (red hulk? she hulk?)... but I don't think there's *enough* there to hold an audience's interest. Then again, I'd have said exactly the same about Thor...

Comment: @JackBNimble No, if it lost money the rate of return would be negative. I added a Wikipedia link to the concept I'm using, but it ultimately comes out to the same thing. Just different notation

Comment: @JasonBaker:   This may be right, but it would be less confusing to express the profit instead of the return.   You could say Ang Lee made $108M on a $137M investment and the (return of 79%) is more clear.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Alright, I clarified my language

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield At least with Thor you don't have a character who actively fights against doing the most (cinematically) interesting thing about him. That's why I think a She-Hulk movie could have value, but we'll see

Comment: Only in Hollywood does a 70%+ profit indicate an "incredibly risky investment".

Comment: @JasonBaker:   I don't really think that's more clear.   The problem is with some ambiguity in the term "earning".   "Profit" is not ambiguous.   (Not that I really care, but just trying to help)

Comment: @JasonBaker saying 75% of budget was the confusing part, it implied a loss.

Comment: @JackBNimble Is it less confusing now? The trouble I'm having is that "rate of return" is the only sensible way to compare the objective "goodness" of the investment, but "rate of return" has a precise definition that (as you point out) isn't obvious to everyone

Comment: Do you know if the budgets listed are just production, or do they include marketing as well?

Comment: The last half of that graphic makes it abundantly clear why other studios are tripping over themselves to make their own MCU-style franchises.  Wow.

Comment: @phantom42 I don't know; Wikipedia cites BoxOfficeMojo for all of them. Considering BOM is owned by IMDB, I *suspect* their numbers include promotion, but I can't be confident

Comment: I don't disagree with your numbers, but it's really a shame. Personally, I thought "The Incredible Hulk" was awesome.

Comment: @KSmarts Something to consider: http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Cancelled_films Not all films even make it to the box office, so it's possible that they could try to make a Hulk movie and it would become so clear it wasn't working out while making it that they just throw the whole thing out, meaning a pure loss with no income attached. Note also the addition on that list of Hulk 2 - there is no mention of how much money they spent on "considering" it, and indeed Universal tried to make it when they failed and it went to Marvel. So there's more to the story of risk than that!

Comment: @BrianDHall That *Hulk 2* was the planned sequel to Ang Lee's *Hulk*, not the MCU one. Also note that *none* of those movies were totally abandoned, they were or are being rebooted instead.

Comment: @KSmarts That's true, and I think that points more to the problem - how do you account for such a possibility, and is any money spent on these films attributed to the cost of the process of delay, start/stop, early development, reboot, etc? That a movie won't get made and everyone involved is just wasting their time, at least until the next person/studio wants a try at it, is still a risk and cost. With Hollywood accounting we know studios exaggerate profit in marketing and then fluff costs everywhere else, so the truth of profit is all the more fuzzy.

Comment: Bear in mind that the studio doesn't get all of the money from the box office. In the USA cinemas get around 50% of the price of each ticket; in the UK they actually get around 75%. And that's before you take into account distribution and marketing costs, which are often not included in the production budget (Hollywood is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_accounting) for shady accounting practices). The conventional wisdom is that a movie has to make twice its budget in order to break even. So the two Hulk films were actually losses for the studios that made them!

Comment: @phantom42 I don't even bother getting out of bed for at least $116M. That's what I'd say if I was rich AF!

Comment: The Hulk is a pretty one dimensional character, unfortunately, at least in the movies that have been made so far.  Whereas many other characters are fun to watch - the way Spidey moves around, for instance - you can only watch a big green rage monster punching tanks for so long before it becomes boring.  The Hulk himself hasn't grown very much in the movies released so far.  Bruce Banner might, but the Hulk is still just punching tanks.

Comment: "...neither Black Widow...[hasn't] had [any] solo films, and there doesn't seem to be any plans to make them...." This aged poorly. :P

Answer (score 16):

Aside from the financial reasons, which should be pretty obvious by now, there is a problem with the character himself.  I should start off by saying that **the following answer is based on what we have seen so far in the first two Hulk movies, not the comic books**.  The comics do a much better job of keeping the character interesting and unpredictable.  The movies, on the other hand, have failed to make him even slightly interesting or unpredictable.

Unfortunately, the Hulk, as he has been portrayed in the two recent movies, is not very interesting. He is too one-dimensional. You can only watch a big green rage monster punching tanks for so long before it becomes boring. He never grows up or learns anything or improves himself. Bruce might do all these things, but the Hulk is still just punching tanks all day. If we take a marginally more successful franchise like Spider-man, we see a more interesting, dynamic character. He's fun to watch - even the way he moves around is visually interesting. The Hulk? Not so much.

Other characters find innovative ways to solve problems. The Hulk is almost incapable of innovation. If a problem can't be solved by punching things, then the Hulk won't solve it. If the conflict can't be resolved by throwing trucks into the air and knocking holes in buildings, then the Hulk won't resolve the conflict. If any degree of intellect is needed to fix things, then you better hope that Bruce Banner is available rather than the Hulk, because intellect isn't his forte.

Ever wonder why movie fights involve so much chatter?  It's because no one can sit through 2 hours of guys hitting each other in near silence.  That's why action movie heroes have an endless supply of witty (or witless) banter and one liners, like "Yippee Kai Ai, Mother------!"  Spider-man is especially prone to witty repartee during his fights.

Now let's look at the Hulk.  What is the dialogue during his fight scenes like?  Absolute silence, or a few grunts and groans, and occasionally, he says "Hulk smash!" or calls his opponent a "puny" something or other.  Not particularly exciting, let alone engaging.

Other superhero movies feature conflict- not merely conflict with the bad guys, but inner conflict, self doubt, and uncertainty.  Spider-man doesn't want to be Spider-man anymore, but then something happens to make him realize how important Spider-man is, and how much good he can do.

This doesn't happen with the Hulk.  Yes, Bruce hates being the Hulk, but he can't do anything about it, so his only alternative is to go somewhere so remote that he can't hurt anyone else.  Peter Parker can hang up his costume and call it quits, however temporarily;  Bruce has no costume to hang up.  He has no choice in the matter.  He will Hulk out whenever he gets mad, whether he wants to or not.

Spider-man actually *does* good things.  The best that the Hulk can do is hope he doesn't kill innocent people while he is a huge green rage monster.  If his tantrums end up producing good results, it is almost accidental, because the Hulk is just punching stuff and yelling.  The fact that Tony Stark needs to build a special suit to fight the Hulk with shows that even his allies can't trust him.

We've been comparing the Hulk to the marginally successful Spider-man reboot.  Now let's compare him to the wildly successful Iron Man franchise.  What makes Iron Man movies so popular- and so entertaining and enjoyable? The superhero part of the character is interesting, dynamic, and adaptable, for starters.  And on top of that, the "alter ego" part of the character is incredibly entertaining, funny, and engaging as well.  The bad guys actually stand a chance of beating him.  He solves problems in a wide variety of very different ways, and uses his brain at least as much as his thrusters and missiles and other paraphernalia.  He is multifaceted and complex - even his flaws are multifaceted and complex.  He is always a human being with doubts, failings, weaknesses, and shortcomings.

The Hulk?  He's not dynamic at all.  The superhero part of the character is totally flat and predictable.  The alter ego part of the character is slightly more compelling, but not by much, and he comes across as kind of whiny and morose.  He doesn't just *have* self doubts and insecurities - he is absolutely consumed by them.  We pity him without actually being sympathetic to his situation.  It is hard to avoid thinking that he might be better off dead.

Whereas Iron Man, in spite of all his flaws, always ends up doing the right thing and finding a way to save the day, the Hulk kind of blunders into doing the right thing- inadvertently- and saving the day- despite the fact that he is just punching tanks, throwing trucks into the air, and knocking holes in buildings.  He never makes a plan, follows through with it, and achieves his goals in the manner he anticipated.  He just manages to punch the right tanks, throw the right trucks, and knock holes in the right buildings, totally unintentionally.

One of the most memorable and hilarious moments from the first Avengers movie was when Thor and the Hulk take down the huge flying caterpillar monster.  How does the Hulk react to their success?  He punches Thor through the wall of Grand Central Terminal.  The only scene that really tops that one is the legendary Hulk/Loki showdown.  How does the Hulk handle this confrontation?  While Loki is ridiculing him, Hulk cuts him off mid-sentence and repeatedly smashes him into the floor like a rag doll.

These scenes show us the strengths and weaknesses of this character.  The strengths:  he is awesome in small doses, especially when he can be used as comic relief, and he can muscle his way through almost any opponent, even a god.  The weaknesses:  he can't do much else.  His whole modus operandi is being a guy who tries to avoid getting mad, until he- wait for it- gets mad.  Then he punches stuff until he isn't mad anymore.  It just isn't enough to build a movie franchise around.  We're too familiar with the premise, and it doesn't hold up for an hour and a half of screen time.  We need more story, and less smashing.

The villains in other movies can be pretty diverse and have very different strengths and specialties.  Iron Man fought a bigger version of Iron Man, then a crazed Russian scientist bent on revenge, then an army of supersoldiers who can melt steel with their hands, and are almost impossible to kill.  Spidey fought the Green Goblin, then Doc Octopus, then Venom *and* Sandman *and* Green Goblin II, then a weird lizard guy...  Some of these villains are smart, some are strong, some are resilient, some are fast, some have powerful weapons.

What kind of villains does the Hulk face?  Strong guys.  That's about it.  In fact, in both of the Hulk movies, the climactic battle was between the Hulk and people who tried to become Hulks themselves.  This is not compelling conflict we're seeing.  It is predictable and tired and, quite frankly, boring as all hell.  An opponent who isn't incredibly strong stands no chance of beating the Hulk, and the Hulk can't really handle anything other than strong guys.

And on top of the fact that audiences expect more from a movie, the Hulk is the kind of character that writers hate.  They want a hero who they can flesh out and give some depth to.  There is some room for that sort of writing in the Bruce Banner character, but no room whatsoever in the Hulk character.  I wouldn't be surprised if many of the most sought after writers in Hollywood would refuse to take on the job of writing another Hulk movie, especially considering the utter failure of the first two films.

Comment: Just to present the opposing viewpoint: the Hulk is easily my favorite Marvel character, and he's completely stolen the show in both Avengers movies. Bruce Banner's (and therefore the Hulk's) inner psychological conflicts are much more interesting than any of the other characters, and his action scenes are more entertaining as well.

Answer (score 0):

In reply to the replier who bashes Hulk as a writeable character.  The television series that ran for 5 seasons and 80 episodes, was popular and ran that long because the used the Banner character as the main character with small doses of the actual Hulk.  The contrast and frustration of Banner losing control, along with the interactions with other people, were some of the prime drivers of that many hours of television.

If a movie were written primarly from the Banner point of view with small appropriately placed doses of the Hulk, I think you'd be easily able to make a compelling character movie.  Finding the balance to make it a Marvel action movie and a compelling character movie would take a talented team to pull off. I'm sure Kevin Feige and team could do it.

The problems that exist now are fitting a movie in the current MCU or rebooting the incredible Hulk. This combined with Universal owning first right of refusal on distribution of Hulk main character movies, makes it highly unlikely we'll get a standalone Hulk movie.  Even though I would love to see of Professor Hulk movie.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please don't use answers to respond to other posts; when you've earned some reputation you'll be able to leave comments, or talk about things in chat.  The only part of this that responds to the question - the issue with rights - is noted in another answer, so this doesn't really add anything new.