# What did the Scarlet Witch show the Hulk/Bruce Banner?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, avengers-age-of-ultron

In the *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, the Scarlet Witch and her brother team up with Ultron against the Avengers for a while. In a few scenes, she uses her mind-powers against them.

She shows Tony Stark (Iron Man) what happens if he fails, with the pile of dead bodies of his friends, and Steve says "You could have prevented this" (or something like that).

She shows Steve Rogers (Captain America) the life he never got to live, with the dancing and the woman he loved.

She made Natasha (Black Widow) relive her painful past, where she remembered her childhood having to dance, and the sterilizing in the secret room.

She had Thor foresee an impending doom, that in the end had him haring off to find his friend and get the information about the Infinity Stones.

But she also showed Bruce Banner (Hulk) something that made him 'turn green' and become Hulk and go on the rampage. Seeing as he had by that time controlled himself a little better, it must have been something really bad that made him change. What did the Scarlet Witch show him?

Comment: There's nothing in the junior novel. It just says that she "Put him under her spell".

Comment: A dead Black Widow I always assumed.

Comment: A reality where She-Hulk gets top billing in the first spin-off Hulk movie.

Comment: [the same question has been asked on Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34195/what-did-the-hulk-see-during-his-nightmare-vision)

Comment: It's not clear that Wanda herself *knows* what she caused them to see - we don't know enough about how her powers work to know if she caused them to see specific things she selected, or more of a general "what you fear the most".

Comment: She mentioned [how much less *The Incredible Hulk* made at the box office](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/85464/440) compared to every other MCU movie.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For that part of the story, there are fan theories and speculations about what he saw. But what he actually saw is not known.

However, remember the words he said to Wanda when he saw her later on AoU.

> [threatening Wanda] I could choke the life out of you without changing
>   a shade.

All the others (of the Avengers team) acted on their vision (on what Wanda showed them). Bruce just lost control and wreaked havoc.

IMO, Bruce's vision was left out for us to figure out or to empathize with your own ethical consciousness. Bruce saw something that made him lose control.

Remember, Bruce probably has the best in self-control or anyone in the Avengers team.

Comment: I like to think he saw a dead Betty Ross, accidentally killed by the Hulk.

Comment: my opinion (and hope) is that they'll show it during Avengers 4.

Answer (score 0):

Bruce always seems as if what he most fears is Hulk taking over. Tahsin is shown all over his storylines. Like in *Thor: Ragnarok*, his horror at being the Hulk for two years and saying he was worried that if he turned again he could never come back. Also, he fears that the Hulk would hurt the world and people who are close to him. For these reasons, I think he would have seen Hulk taking permanent control and also killing the Avengers and others.

Answer (score 0):

### There was no vision.

We didn't see Bruce Banner get a vision, and there's no reason to believe that a vision was necessary to make him "Hulk out". He asks on the radio:

> BANNER: Guys, is this a Code Green?
>
> [Radio static]

Because he got no response, I believe the filmmakers wanted us to see that he intentionally Hulked out because he couldn't get a response, ergo the need was desperate enough that he *had* to go green.